# Ubuntu 13.10 - i am running in KIOSK train station public place, but this autoupdate window is annoying every day. How to remove it please?

Tags: upgrade, uninstall, notification, openbox, autohide

I need to remove this auto update notification dialog window which is very annoying and scary for public location where people is clicking the system and breaking it down to crash every day.

I tried to remove the Autoupdate notification window with following, but still every single day its showing in the screen and its very annoying like Ubuntu Virus, very disturbing and not respecting privacy, such as i do not want it to ever show, but it keeps showing by force.

```
Try: sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop

Try: apt-get install dconf-editor
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && dconf-editor
via GUI > go to com->ubuntu->update-notifer-> no-show-notifications and enable it

Try: Disable Auto uploader
$ comment outall /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades 
$ add new line /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

But still the Auto-Update Notification Dialog window appears. 
I am unable to remove it for completely.

Comment: I thought that was answer but after running for while that also did not worked. Even more options also just fails.

Comment: Please modify the original of the duplicate question with the new information, and withdraw the accepted answer (Green check mark) if possible.

Comment: Did that. But why nobody knows how to protect this VIRUS/SPAM from Ubuntu 13.10? Everyday without my permission its asking auto update. I dont want it to do oversmart tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the configuration at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades to comment out the line:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

Remove the second line that ends with -security

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

That should disable automatic updates since there is no location for it to pull updates from after commenting the location out.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JIfjzds.png - That was set few weeks ago please see this screen shot: but still today and everyday i have this annoying Software Updater

Comment: `sun       2639  0.6  1.2 825604 100900 ?       SNl  20:20   0:08 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager --no-update --no-focus-on-map
`

Comment: This is the package every single day its annoying the world with its ugly popup dialog box, its like no respect for user privacy at all.

Comment: On the dialog box that pops up, can you press the "Settings..." button and take a screen shot of the dialog that opens up. There are several options there that might be worth disabling.  Uncheck the entries above, and change to "Never" for the drop down menus. That should disable the updates. Here is a copy of mine with updates enabled. http://imgur.com/U00skGp

Comment: YES - i did changed like you mentioned but still same its not disabling. Again and again the popup comes.

Comment: Is there anyway to find in the whole directory who is executing the script name "update-manager" from /usr/bin ? Then we can exploit that python3 script into empty code and then even it executes wont show anything.

Comment: Did you fixed it yet? Its not working yet.

Comment: Did you FIXED it yet?